# On iOS, if drawRect doesn't use the rect that was passed in, does it matter if [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:rect] passes in a rect?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

That is, if

```
[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:rect];
```

is called, and `rect` is very carefully calculated for the region that needs to be redrawn, but if our `drawRect` code doesn't care about `rect` and draw everything anyway, can the iOS system still somehow improve the drawing speed?  (or possibly improve very little?)  This question probably requires somebody who is very familiar with UIKit/CoreGraphics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways the answer could be yes:

1. You can clip to the rectangle, in which case anything outside it won't be painted, even if you draw in it. Drawing outside the rectangle won't be free, but it will be cheaper. iOS can't do this for you because you might deliberately ignore the rect, or use the rect but also draw something else elsewhere in your bounds unconditionally. (Though that other thing should probably be another view.)
2. Even if your *current* `drawRect:` doesn't use the rectangle, you might go back to that code later to optimize it. As you're probably aware, one very good way to do that—if it's at all possible—is to use the rectangle to decide what you draw. Even if you're not doing that now, you may do it in the future, and specifying changed rects now means that many fewer things to change then.
3. A corollary to #3 is that even if what you're drawing now *can't* be so optimized, you may decide in a future major version to completely change what the view draws to something that can. Again, specifying changed rects now means that many fewer things to do in the future.
4. Subviews. If your view doesn't actually draw some of the things that the user sees in it, but rather delegates (not in the Cocoa/Cocoa Touch sense) those things to subviews, then you might override `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` to send `setNeedsDisplay:` messages to subviews—and *only* the subviews whose frames intersect the rect—before calling `super`. (And UIView's implementation might already do this. You should test it.)

Answer (score 1):

If your `drawRect:` implementation ignores the rect passed in and draws the entire view, any optimization of the rect passed to `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` is for nought.

The "needs display" rect is passed straight through; the only thing it's there for is for the `drawRect:` implementation to use for ignoring unnecessary drawing. Once your `drawRect:` implementation is entered, the system can't tell whether your drawing outside the passed rect is intentional, so all the drawing really happens (performance implications included).

Depending on what you're drawing and how, it's not too difficult to restrict your `drawRect:` implementation to at least make some use of the rect passed in. Everything you want to draw has a bounding rect, whether it's a chunk of text or a bezier path or an image or just a rect you're filling with some color. Surround each bit to drawing with a `CGRectIntersectsRect()` test -- you won't completely restrict your drawing to the passed in rect that way, but you'll at least eliminate anything that doesn't touch that rect from needing to be drawn.

Comment: so I guess if my drawing takes up most of the CPU time, then it doesn't help.  What can be help might be the tiny bit of the time saved by the GPU to transfer that small rectangle into the current display buffer or whatever, and it probably is very tiny?